# Wrong flag setting for SUBSTRING_INDEX operator

Tags: mysql

I compiled a query that chooses a link from the 'ss' column:

'ss' column:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img data-src="https://asd.com/123.jpg" srcset="https://asd.com/234.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img data-src="https://asd.com/123.jpg" srcset="https://asd.com/234.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img data-src="https://asd.com/123.jpg" srcset="https://asd.com/234.jpg"></a>
```

Here is my SQL:

```
UPDATE post SET still1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'nk\"><img data-src=\"',-3 ),'.jpg\" s',1 )
UPDATE post SET still2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'nk\"><img data-src=\"',-2 ),'.jpg\" s',1 )
UPDATE post SET still3 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'nk\"><img data-src=\"',-1 ),'.jpg\" s',1 )
```

I refer to the first link using the -3 flag. When the number of links is three, everything works fine. But when there are fewer of them (there cannot be more than three of them) - an incorrect result is issued. Is there an alternative to the first link? (for cases when links, only 2 for example).

Here is one and non-working options that I went through:

```
UPDATE post SET still1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'nk\"><img data-src=\"',1 ),'.jpg\" s',-1 )
```

I can not understand why this option does not work.

### UPD:

Okey, here is a simple query that I was looking for:

```
UPDATE post SET still1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'.jpg\" s',1 ),'nk\"><img data-src=\"',-1 )
UPDATE post SET still2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( ss,'.jpg\" s',2 ),'nk\"><img data-src=\"',-1 )
...
```

However, I still did not understand the recursive MySQL logic.

Comment: What are you trying to parse from the html? Or what data do you need? i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I need this link: https://asd.com/123.jpg in my still1, still2,, still3 columns.

Comment: The above links are in the database, in the field "xfields"... translation difficulties

Comment: Why not treat it as xml and extract the data using built in xml handling/xpath?

Comment: I have not enough experience for this, besides, I am dealing with encrypted IonCube code... A small update of stills1, stills2, stills3 is all I need. I’m sure I’m missing out on some little detail in the SQL request.

Comment: "Why not treat it as xml and extract the data using built in xml handling/xpath?" great idea but the problem is that  his html `<img>` tags in his document isnt valid xml @CaiusJard see what i mean https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5s4utGJftWPxH6sqpo7FyH/1 .. his img tags are missing the closing `/` which is required in xml..

Comment: Is there a cheap hack to be made with string manipulation (find <img, find next >, replacewith />) to overcome the lack of img closure?